# google pie chart retrieving info from json file error - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous, google-visualization

I have created a google pie chart which gets data from a JSON file. however i have an error even though the chart displays correctly. the error is: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

If i change the async to true, the error goes away, however then the pie chart does not get displayed, and it instead says that the table has no columns.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({         
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
            var options = {


        };

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      chart.draw(data);



 chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, false);
};
        </script>       

    <body>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div id="piechart" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to wait until the request is done,
move everything inside the `done` callback...

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "getData.php",
    dataType: "json",
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var options = {};
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
};
```